# How m[-1,-50] works on matrix in R?

Tags: r

It's from the Doc's example of `persp` function, like this:

```
x <- seq(-1.95, 1.95, length = 30)
y <- seq(-1.95, 1.95, length = 35)
z <- outer(x, y, function(a, b) a*b^2)
nrz <- nrow(z)
ncz <- ncol(z)
# Create a function interpolating colors in the range of specified colors
jet.colors <- colorRampPalette( c("blue", "green") )
# Generate the desired number of colors from this palette
nbcol <- 100
color <- jet.colors(nbcol)
# Compute the z-value at the facet centres
zfacet <- z[-1, -1] + z[-1, -ncz] + z[-nrz, -1] + z[-nrz, -ncz]
# Recode facet z-values into color indices
facetcol <- cut(zfacet, nbcol)
persp(x, y, z, col = color[facetcol], phi = 30, theta = -30)
```

So you can see, it creates a new matrix, which is important for generating the graph color, but I still don't understand what's the meaning of `z[-1, -ncz]` is (the `ncz` is a big number like 50) and what the new matrix `zfacet` meaning finally?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this:

```
R> x <- 1:5
R> x[-3]
[1] 1 2 4 5
R> x[-c(2,4)]
[1] 1 3 5
R>
```

In R, a *negative index* excludes the element(s) at that index position.